# Google map on camera change going in a circular loop

Tags: android, google-maps

On camera change gets called again and again while animation is going on in google maps. Is it getting triggered because the animation has not finished? If so, how to get the callback which notifies the animation has stopped.

Here is my code:

```
 map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        showLocations(location);
    }
});

private void showLocations() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Marker m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlngs.get(i))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.some_icon)));
        markers.add(m);
    }
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker marker : markers) {
        builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `map.animateCamera()` causes the `OnCameraChangeListener` to be called, so you can't change the camera unless you're planning on removing the listener as part of its logic. For example:

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
    showLocations(location);
  }
});
```